# short vs long message - input placeholder

Tags: website-design, forms, input-fields

I'm working on a profile update form, it got me wondering - what's the pros&cons of displaying a short placeholder vs a long placeholder?

First candidate: ***Current Password***

[image]

Second candidate: ***Type Your Current Password***

[image]

Comment: Either way be consistent.  The second should be Type New Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Current Password** without a doubt. The typing clarification isn't necessary, and as general rule, if it doesn't make it better, discard it.

Consider:

- That kind of form (password changing) is the same in almost every site. Also it's placed in the same section (edit profile, settings, etc).
- Inside a text input, specially a **password input**, to add the "Type your" text **will be redundant**. As mentioned in [Don't make me think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789723107) users **scan** pages, and that extra text will add some cognitive load unnecessarily.

The thing I'd be tempted to change is the "Password" title for something like "Change Password", but that will be useful or not depending on the context of the whole form.